# Cannot boot into Ubuntu 12.04 after adding an additional hard drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I've installed both Ubuntu and Windows7 on my laptop, I've replaced my internal hard drive with ssd, and it worked well (both Ubuntu and Win7). However the space is just not enough so I put my hard drive back with an adapter (I'm not sure what it's called, it's a case that replaces original CD-ROM and can place my hard drive inside), and it just doesn't work any more.

**Devices**

1. laptop with only one hard drive slot
2. a 120GB ssd installed at the internal slot (windows /dev/sda3, ubuntu /dev/sda6)
3. a 500GB traditional hard drive at CD-ROM slot(with an adaptor)

**Situation**

1. at first I tried to use windows bootloader(which I used to when no second hard drive), and the Windows part worked fine, but when I select the Ubuntu entry I get stuck and it shows

> Try (hd0,0):NTFS5: no ang0
>
> Try (hd0,1):NTFS5: no ang0
>
> Try (hd0,2): Extended
>
> Try (hd0,3): invalid or null
>
> Try (hd0,4): NTFS5: no ang0
>
> Try (hd0,5): Extended
>
> Try (hd0,5): NTFS5: no ang0
>
> Try (hd0,6): Extended
>
> Try (hd0,6): Ext2:

2. Then I tried installing grub to mbr and using grub as default, with no second harddrive it loads grub first and both Windows and Ubuntu worked well, but if I install the second harddrive it just load back to the original Windows bootloader( I just can't figure it out why?), and the situation is same as above.
3. I'm quite sure it's loading the bootloader from ssd not the other drive because there's a jumper on the second hdd and if I switch it then it loads the second hdd's mbr( which has four entries)

**Question**

How can I boot into both system without reinstalling any of them?

I'm sure both systems are not corrupted since I can boot into both whenever I remove the second hdd.

Comment: Check your bios your computer is probably trying to boot from CD/DVD first and now its been replaced with a hard drive, not containing your OS,thus could be the cause of the your problems.Change boot order in bios

Comment: Thx for reply, but I've checked it's booting the right device bcuz it loads the bootloader in mbr section of my ssd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)